# Ping vs CPU usage

Tags: ping, cpu-usage

I’m working on some measurements and the ping results are intriguing me. I tested it in several scenarios and the results are the same: the ping results are better when the CPU load is higher.

The Round Trip Time decreases from about 30 usec with low CPU to ~5 or less usec with high CPU. In a quadcore machine, a single CPU being used already causes this effect

Anyone has seen this kind of behavior before? It seems to be scheduling of the Linux kernel but I’m not sure.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

It takes a few extra microseconds to wake up the CPU. This is the tradeoff with power management, it makes latency a bit worse.

Comment: that's a great theory, do you know how can I test it?

Comment: Turn off power management and watch the difference go away.

Comment: thank you (: I'll try to turn it off and I'll get back to you!